# Creating lists with variable lengths Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a list with a length determined by a user input.

How would I do this?

Example: If the user inputs 3 I need a list with 3 indexes.

Comment: Hint: You can *append* to a list to add extra elements.

Comment: what part is not clear? How to get an integer from a user? How to create a list of a given length (what content do you want to put in it e.g., how do you think a list of 3 items should look like)?

Comment: Not very good at python yet. I just created an empty list and appended it with the inputs from the user. idk how to post the code or else I would show you. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Something like this: D = [ ]
while Days >= n:
    print("Enter the major event for day", n, ": ", end="")
    x = input( )
    D.append(x)
    n = n + 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do you want to fill the list with? If you just want a list with n indexes:

```
n = user_input_length
list = [None for x in range(n)]
```

Comment: `None` is immutable (moreover it is a singletone); you could use `your_list = [None] * n` (don't use `list` as a name; it shadows the builtin).

Answer (score 1):

You can take in input, then populate your list:

```
import random
num = int(input('How long do you want the list? ')) #5
lst = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(num)]
print lst #[6, 1, 2, 1, 8]
```

Comment: there is no `raw_input()` in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using the append  function to do what I needed to do.

Comment: How do you post your code in that grey box?

Comment: @inlakechalakin you have to indent it four spaces